# custom_element_apigen gives an error importing a Polymer element to Dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

In Dart I'm trying to import to an element written for Polymer (in particular paper-typeahead-input and paper-typeahead) using custom_element_apigen.

I get this error when I run the apigen script:

> pub run custom_element_apigen:update configfile.yaml

```
[32m1 of 1: lib\src\paper-typeahead-input/paper_typeahead_input.html[0mUnhandled exception:
Uncaught Error: ProcessException: %1 non ├¿ un'applicazione di Win32 valida.

    Command: packages/custom_element_apigen/src/js/process_elements.sh lib\src\paper-typeahead-input/paper_typeahead_input.html
Stack Trace:
#0      _parseFile.<_parseFile_async_body> (package:custom_element_apigen/generate_dart_api.dart)
#1      _asyncCatchHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:core-patch/core_patch.dart:14)
#2      _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1171)
#3      _Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:521)
#4      _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:580)
#5      _Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:376)
#6      _Future._asyncCompleteError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:431)
#7      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43)
#8      _microtaskLoopEntry (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52)
#9      _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:394)
#10     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:414)
#11     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:148)

#0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:895)
#1      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43)
#2      _microtaskLoopEntry (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52)
#3      _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:394)
#4      _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:414)
#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:148)
```

Could someone tell me what is related to? becouse I don't understand.....thanks very much!

Comment: Looks like it tries to execute a bash script (`process_elements.sh`) on Windows. Maybe the package doesn't support Windows. Can you check what commands the file `process_elements.sh` contains?

Comment: the script command inside process_elements.sh is:

node packages/custom_element_apigen/src/js/analyze.js $*

Comment: That wouldn't be too hard to port to Windows if node works well on Windows (which I assume). A bit more work would it be to make `custom_element_apigen` call a `process_elements.bat` file instead. Did you install node.js and the modules mentioned in the readme of `custom_element_apigen` anyway?

Comment: Yes I've installed all modules requested..... I only not installed packages with bower (becouse they are in pubspec.yaml and get them via pub get....). Maybe this tool is only for linux or mac? I may try in the next days on a linux machine, do you think would go better? thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, to me it looks like it currently only supports Linux or OSX. You could file an issue in the GitHub repo to ass Windows support.

Comment: @Matteo G., I am with same problem in Windows. Did you get to resolve this problem?